# I cannot print color escape codes to the terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, rust

When I run this script:

```
fn main() {
    // \033[0;31m <- Red
    // \033[0m <- No Color
    println!("\033[0;31mSO\033[0m")
}
```

I expect to get

```
SO #in red letters
```

However, I get:

```
33[0;31mSO33[0m
```

When I ran similar script in Go or Python, I get the expected output. What is going on? What am I missing? How do fix this?

I am using:

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.3.0 (9a92aaf19 2015-09-15)
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Rust 1.3.0 does not seem to support octal escape strings such as `\033`.
Instead, you can use hexadecimal escape strings like `\x1b`.

```
fn main(){
  println!("\x1b[0;31mSO\x1b[0m")
}
```

Updated: This answer was intended that "you cannot use octal character such as `\033`, use hexadecimal character `\x1b` instead",
but If you want to know about [ANSI Escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), maybe this [gist](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797) is useful.

Comment: My God, I searched high and low trying to find the answer to this question. Every where else you find crap like "use this crate" or "use that crate". THIS is the correct answer to this question. Thank you so much for answering the question directly!

Comment: FWIW, the reason why folks direct you to a crate is so that your coloring works on Windows.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 Not everyone cares about Windows though.

Comment: I didn't say or imply they did.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if a link to where this is stated in the docs in included in this answer. It took me a long time to find this answer, and I'd like to know where in the docs (if at all) it is so I know where I went wrong trying to find it.

Comment: @Max888 This answer was intended that "you cannot use octal character such as \033, use hexadecimal character \x1b instead", but If you want to know about [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), maybe this [gist](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797) is useful.

Comment: @ymonad thanks, I know about escape codes, I just meant that I would appreciate a link to where in the Rust docs it states you can't use \033. Either 1) The docs don't mention it, and it is just random knowledge that is handed from person to person on the web. or 2) It is in the docs and I would like to know where since I couldn't find it and would like to know my way around the docs better. Hope that makes sense, I wasn't critisicing your answer, just asking for this extra info :)