# How do I print colored text to the terminal in Rust?

Tags: rust, terminal, output

How do I output colored text to the terminal using Rust? I've tried using the special escape characters that I found in [this python answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/287944/16775594), but they just print literally. Here is my code:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("\033[93mError\033[0m");
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/33139248 .

Comment: Good point! I certainly hadn't found that question in my pre-post search. Does that mean we should close this question?

Comment: Yeah, in a perfect world the later question should probably be closed with a link that it is duplicating the original. But I'm new to Rust and haven't read these posts super closely, so I left it as it is and just noted the duplication.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Rust doesn't have octal escape sequences. You have to use hexadecimal:

```rust
println!("\x1b[93mError\x1b[0m");
```

See also https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/30491.

What happens, and the reason the compiler does not complain, is that `\0` *is* a valid escape sequence in Rust - and represents the NULL character (ASCII code 0). It is just that Rust, unlike C (and Python), does not allow you to specify octal number after that. So it considers the `33` to be normal characters to print.

Comment: I just filed an issue in clippy: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/7981

Answer (score 78):

You can use the [`colored` crate](https://docs.rs/colored/latest/colored/) to do this. Here is a simple example. with multiple colors and formats:

```rust
use colored::Colorize;

fn main() {
    println!(
        "{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, and some normal text.",
        "Bold".bold(),
        "Red".red(),
        "Yellow".yellow(),
        "Green Strikethrough".green().strikethrough(),
        "Blue Underline".blue().underline(),
        "Purple Italics".purple().italic()
    );
}
```

Sample color output:

[image: colored and formatted text in the terminal with Rust]

Each of the format functions (`red()`, `italics()`, etc.) can be used on its own as well as in combination with others. But if you use *colors* in combination with each other, only the last color to be set shows.

Comment: Another crate to check is https://lib.rs/crates/termcolor and its wrapper https://lib.rs/crates/termcolor_output (disclaimer - I've created the latter, but not the former).

Comment: @Cerberus I encourage you to post another answer, if you like! The more the merrier ;-)!

Comment: Also I don't think you need to use the `format!` macro every time - you can just call the `Colorize` functions on the actual `&str` (e.g. `"Bold".bold()` would work instead of `format!("Bold").bold()`)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
cargo add inline_colorization
```

and in main.rs:

```
use inline_colorization::*;

fn main() {
  println!("Lets the user {color_red}colorize{color_reset} the and {style_underline}style the output{style_reset} text using inline variables");
}
```

I am the creator of the mentioned rust crate.

Comment: I like this one because it matches closely to the design pattern I use with Python's f strings

Comment: Is this available on github? I found the crate but a quick Google search doesn't find anything

Comment: https://github.com/eliasjonsson023/inline_colorization